# Tumblr photo post caption positioning

Tags: css, post, photo, tumblr, caption

I was hoping somebody would be able to help with the following query...

I've setup a Tumblr blog on which I'm going to regularly post photo sets.
I'd like to write a brief description with each set. I can do this
within the caption field that sits below the image. The problem with
this is that when including multiple images within a post the description
will be lost at the bottom, below all the images.

I'd like the caption to be positioned at the top of the post, before
the images so that viewers can read the description first.

Here's a link to the blog, though empty for now I've inserted a test
post to show how the information is displayed. The black block
represents an image set,'Coming Soon' was entered in the caption field.

http://rg-e.tumblr.com/

Any thoughts/or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would need to see your theme's code to provide you with specifics, but you just need to move where the `{block:Caption}` is being rendered.

An example:

```
{block:Photoset}
    {block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}

    {Photoset-500}
{/block:Photoset}
```

This will put the photoset's caption *above* the photoset.

Comment: Fantastic, I'll look into this.

Comment: No problem! If I've solved your answer, just hit the checkbox beside it - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand upon graygimore's answer - changing the position of the {block:Caption} - Here's the exact code I modified from my custom tumblr theme. Worked a treat.

Thanks again.

```
{block:Photo}
                    <section class="caption group">
                                {block:Caption}
                                    <div class="cont">{Caption}</div>
                                {/block:Caption}
                                {block:ContentSource}
                                    <div class="cont content_source">
                                        <a href="{SourceURL}">
                                            {lang:Source}:
                                            {block:SourceLogo}
                                                <img src="{BlackLogoURL}" width="{LogoWidth}" height="{LogoHeight}" alt="{SourceTitle}" />
                                            {/block:SourceLogo}
                                            {block:NoSourceLogo}
                                                {SourceTitle}
                                            {/block:NoSourceLogo}
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                {/block:ContentSource}
                            </section>
                        <section class="top media" style="display:block;">
                             {LinkOpenTag}<img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}"> {LinkCloseTag}{Question}
                        </section>
                    {/block:Photo}
```